# D3: How do I chain transitions for nested data?

Tags: d3.js, transition

I'm attempting to make a visualization with a multistage animation. [Here's a contrived fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CTXz8/24/) illustrating my problem (code below).

In [this visualization](http://jsfiddle.net/CTXz8/24/) the boxes in each row should turn green when the entire group has finished moving to the right column. IOW, when the first row (containing 3 boxes) is entirely in the right column, all the boxes should turn from black to green, but the second row, having only partially moved to the right column at this point, would remain black until it, too, is completely in the right column.

**I'm having a hard time designing this transition.**

Basic chaining without a delay immediately turns each box green once its finished moving (this is how it's working currently). Not good enough.

On the other hand creating a delay for the chain is difficult, since the effective delay per group is based on the number of boxes it has and I don't think this count is available to me.

It's like I need the transition to happen at mixed levels of granularity.

How should I go about doing this?

[The fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CTXz8/24/) (code below)

```
var data = [
  ["x", "y", "z"],
  ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
];

var svg = d3.select("svg");
var group = svg.selectAll("g").data(data)
    .enter()
        .append("g")
            .attr("transform", function(d, i) { 
                return "translate(0, " + (40 * i) + ")"; 
            });

var box = group.selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) { return d; });

box.enter()
    .append("rect")
        .attr("width", 30)
        .attr("height", 30)
        .attr("x", function(d, i) { return 60 + 30 * i; })
    .transition()
        .delay(function(d, i) { return 250 + 500 * i; })
            .attr("x", function(d, i) { return 300 + 30 * i; })
    .transition()
        .attr("style", "fill:green");
        // I probably need a delay here but it'd be based off the
        // number of elements in the nested data and I don't know
        // how to get that count
        .attr("style", "fill:green");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to get the effect you want, it's a little tricky though. You can customize the behavior of a transition at the begining and end of a transition. If you add a function to the end of the transition that detects if the transitioned element is the last in the group, you select all the rectangles in the group and apply the change to them.

```
box.enter()
    .append("rect")
        .attr("width", 30)
        .attr("height", 30)
        .attr("x", function(d, i) { return 60 + 30 * i; })
        .transition()
        .delay(function(d, i) { return 250 + 500 * i; })
            .attr("x", function(d, i) { return 300 + 30 * i; })
            .each('end', function(d, i) { 
                var g = d3.select(d3.select(this).node().parentNode),
                    n = g.selectAll('rect')[0].length;
                if (i === n - 1) { 
                    g.selectAll('rect').attr('fill', 'green');
                }
            });
```

More details in the transitions [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#wiki-each), a working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pnavarrc/Tqtqy/1/).